# Is it possible to use angular2 keyframe animation for canvas drawing

Tags: angular, animation, html5-canvas, keyframe

I have read about the [Angular animation interface with keyframes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#multi-step-animations-with-keyframes) - and would like to use the same interface for general object properties - this would allow to use the same api also for canvas animations.

Is this possible in Angular? The example only mentions css properties..

iam open to tips in any direction :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular animation interface sits on top of the [Web Animation API](https://devdocs.io/dom/web_animations_api) which can only animate DOM elements:

> The Web Animations API allows for synchronizing and timing changes to the presentation of a Web page, i.e. animation of DOM elements. It does so by combining two models: the Timing Model and the Animation Model.

You can however look at the [polyfill](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/tree/dev/src) for the API and see how it is being implemented and transfer that to use for canvas.

You can also "hack" it by applying animation to a DOM element that is out of view, then each frame grab the position and transforms and apply them to canvas. However, there are certain performance overheads that may not be desirable as well as some limits (like 3D transforms) so I would recommend looking into rewriting the polyfill for canvas as a better option (or just use CSS+DOM).

### Proof-of-concept hack

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var div = document.getElementById("test");

// extract CSS animation and apply to canvas
(function loop() {
  c.width = c.width;
  ctx.fillText("Canvas", c.width-50, c.height-10);

  var cs = getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue("transform"); // get 2D trans. matrix
  
  // strip text and convert to array
  var start = cs.indexOf("(")+1;
  var txt = cs.substr(start, cs.length - start - 1);
  var arr = txt.split(",");
  
  ctx.setTransform.apply(ctx, arr);
  ctx.font = "16px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillText(div.innerHTML, 0, 10);

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})()
```

```css
body {overflow:hidden}
#c {border: 1px solid #777}
#test {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  animation: testRot infinite 3s linear;
  font:16px sans-serif;
}

@keyframes testRot {
  0% {transform: rotate(0)}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
<div id=test>This text and animation comes from DOM</div>
```